# How to run two queries on the same table for different values within a column (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I would like to run a query in SQL Server for two cases:

1) Check that a column "ValueType" = 0. If so, return the query results with another column "Value" divided by 1000.

2) If "ValueType" = 1, return the results with Value column unmodified.

I have tried using a UNION as seen in the code below, but it is returning the error: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified`

Both of these queries work as individual `SELECT` queries. I've tried using the suggested syntax for UNION in the documentation.

I'm pretty new to SQL, so I can provide more information if necessary, I'm hoping it's just an issue with my use of UNION.

```
SELECT 
       mv.[ID]
      ,mv.[TransactionId]
      ,mv.[Timestamp]
      ,mv.[Value]/1000 as "Value"
      ,c.[ChargePoint_ID]
      ,c.[ConnectorId]
    FROM [dbo].[MeterValues] mv
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Connections] c
        ON mv.Connection_ID = c.ID
  WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-09-04' AND '2018-11-01'
  AND ReadingContext = 3
  AND ValueType = 0
  AND ChargePoint_ID IN (SELECT [ChargePoint_ID]
            FROM [dbo].[ChargeDetailRecords]
            WHERE [AuthenticationId] = 'XXX'
            )
UNION
SELECT 
       mv.[ID]
      ,mv.[TransactionId]
      ,mv.[Timestamp]
      ,mv.[Value]
      ,c.[ChargePoint_ID]
      ,c.[ConnectorId]
    FROM [dbo].[MeterValues] mv
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Connections] c
        ON mv.Connection_ID = c.ID
  WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-09-04' AND '2018-11-01'
  AND ReadingContext = 3
  AND ValueType = 1
  AND ChargePoint_ID IN (SELECT [ChargePoint_ID]
             FROM [dbo].[ChargeDetailRecords]
             WHERE [AuthenticationId] = 'XXX'

ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC
```

Comment: Please check .........Case ...........When statement in SQLserver may be that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    mv.[ID],
    mv.[TransactionId],
    mv.[Timestamp],
    CASE WHEN ValueType = 0 THEN mv.[Value] / 1000
         WHEN ValueType = 1 THEN mv.[Value] END AS [Value]
    c.[ChargePoint_ID],
    c.[ConnectorId]
FROM [dbo].[MeterValues] mv
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Connections] c
    ON mv.Connection_ID = c.ID
WHERE
    [Value] IN (0, 1) AND
    [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-09-04' AND '2018-11-01' AND
    ReadingContext = 3 AND
    ChargePoint_ID IN (SELECT [ChargePoint_ID] FROM [dbo].[ChargeDetailRecords]
                       WHERE [AuthenticationId] = 'XXX');
```

The two halves of your query appear identical, except regarding how `Value` is handled, and a single condition in the `WHERE` clause which checks `ValueType`.  There is not reason for a `UNION` here, from what I can see.

Note that there is a lingering issue about what happens should `ValueType` not be zero or one.  In this case, I am returning `NULL`, but perhaps you don't need to worry about this is values other than zero or one could never happen.

Comment: Yup, this works, thanks! NULL expression not required but nice thought :)

Comment: ACTUALLY...instead of filling the column with NULL, is it possible to just only query the rows where ValueType = 0 or 1? I realised there is also rows with ValueType = 8, and I would rather not return those rows at all @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Try below, union not required:

```
SELECT 

     mv.[ID]
      ,mv.[TransactionId]
      ,mv.[Timestamp]
      ,CASE WHEN ValueType = 0 THEN mv.[Value]/1000 
            WHEN ValueType = 1 THEN mv.[Value] ELSE NULL --You can amend the ELSE as you wish
            END AS Value
      ,c.[ChargePoint_ID]
      ,c.[ConnectorId]
    FROM [dbo].[MeterValues] mv
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Connections] c
        ON mv.Connection_ID = c.ID
  WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-09-04' AND '2018-11-01'
  AND ReadingContext = 3
  AND ValueType IN (0,1)
  AND ChargePoint_ID IN (SELECT [ChargePoint_ID]
            FROM [dbo].[ChargeDetailRecords]
            WHERE [AuthenticationId] = 'XXX'
```